Wasm data not rendering on html canvas
I made a wasm/js application that should display a array of colors on a html canvas, but nothing is displaying. heres the c code:
void print(int val);

int screen[57600];


int* get_screen(){
        print(1);
        return &screen[0];
}

html:
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var importObject = {env: {print: function(arg){
                console.log(arg)
            },
            }}

            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 360;
            canvas.height = 180;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            
            
            WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('fizzbuzz.wasm'), importObject).then((obj) => {
                var offset = obj.instance.exports.get_screen()
                var display = new Uint32Array(obj.instance.exports.memory.buffer, offset, 57600)
                requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                    for (let i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
                        const uint32 = display[i];
                        
                        // Extract individual bytes (RGBA components)
                        const r = (uint32 >> 24) & 0xFF;
                        const g = (uint32 >> 16) & 0xFF;
                        const b = (uint32 >> 8) & 0xFF;
                        const a = uint32 & 0xFF;

                        // Render pixel onto the canvas
                        const x = i % 360;
                        const y = Math.floor(i / 360);
                        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a})`;
                        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                    }
                    
                    requestAnimationFrame(arguments.callee)
                })
                
            })
            

            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


the Makefile:
display.wasm: display.c
    clang --target=wasm32 -emit-llvm -c -S display.c
    llc -march=wasm32 -filetype=obj display.ll
    wasm-ld --export-all --allow-undefined --no-entry -o display.wasm display.o
    wasm2wat display.wasm > display.wat #just for debugging

run_wasm: display.wasm
    python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1

clean:
    rm -rf display.wasm


there are no errors in the console and no reason(in my opinion) that it shouldn't work.
i tried(in the c code) to check for value changes from the js and infact the js can change the values(it also works the other way around)

Please tell us what debugging you have tried - e.g. console.logs in that requestAnimationFrame function to check exactly what is being drawn.

sorry to everyone who's time I wasted i set the opacity to 0 as default that is the reason nothing was showing up
